# How can I log the CorrelationManager.ActivityId with NLog

Tags: .net, logging, nlog, trace

How can I log the `CorrelationManager.ActivityId` as a separate field?

Here is my current NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${basedir}/Logs" />

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Mongo"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Mongo"
            name="mongoCustom"
            includeDefaults="false"
            connectionString="mongodb://localhost/FooLogging"
            collectionName="authLogs">

      <field name="Date" layout="${longdate:universalTime=true}" />
      <field name="Level" layout="${level}"/>
      <field name="Message" layout="${message}" />
      <field name="Logger" layout="${logger}"/>
      <field name="Exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <field name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" />
      <field name="ThreadName" layout="${threadname}" />
      <field name="ProcessID" layout="${processid}" />
      <field name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
      <field name="UserName" layout="${windows-identity}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="mongoCustom" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no built in support for `CorrelationManager.ActivityId`.

However you can create your own layout render which outputs it:

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("activityid")]
public class ActivityIdLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.ToString());
    }
}
```

You also need to register it with:

```
 ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
      .RegisterDefinition("activityid", typeof(ActivityIdLayoutRenderer));
```

Then you can use it in your target definition with:

```
<target xsi:type="Mongo">
      <!-- ... -->
      <field name="ActivityId" layout="${activityid}" />
</target>
```

As an alternative solution you can also you the [Event Context Layout Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Event-Context-Layout-Renderer) to output any custom property like the ActivityId but in this case you have to include it every time when you log something.

Comment: thx! I opened up an issue as well: github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/332

Answer (score 5):

${activityid} was added in NLog v4.1.
https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer